# Java - create a maze with a unique solution

Tags: java, path, maze

So I'm currently trying to make a java program that finds a single solution through a maze. To do this I'm using a create method which creates a maze that has a unique solution:

```
private void Create ( int x, int y, int val ) {
        int[] perm = randPerm( 4 );
        m[x][y] ^= val;  
        for (int i=0; i<4; ++i) {
            int p = perm[i];
            if (m[x+DX[p]][y+DY[p]] == 15) {
                m[x][y] ^= TWO[p];  
                Create( x+DX[p], y+DY[p], TWO[p^2] );
            }
        }
    }
```

So before I start making the method to solve the maze I'm trying to figure out how the above method always creates a maze with a unique path (like what's p^2 
used for). So how does the above method work?

```
 private int[][] m;   // maze representation
   private int rows;    // number of rows in the maze
   private int cols;    // number of columns in the maze
   private final static byte[] TWO = { 1, 2, 4, 8, 16};
   private final static byte[] DX  = { 0,+1, 0,-1};
   private final static byte[] DY  = {-1, 0,+1, 0};
   private boolean done;  // used in finding a single solution.
   private long   count;  // used in finding the number of solutions.
   private Random r;      // for generating random integers.

public Maze ( int nr, int nc, int seed ) {
      r = new Random( seed );
      rows = nr;  cols = nc;
      m = new int[nr+2][nc+2];
      for (int r=1; r<=nr; ++r )
         for (int c=1; c<=nc; ++c )
            m[r][c] = 15;
      for (int r=0; r<nr+2; ++r )
            m[r][0] = m[r][nc+1] = 16;
      for (int c=0; c<nc+2; ++c )
         m[0][c] = m[nr+1][c] = 16;
      Create( nr/2+1, nc/2+1, 0 );
   }

private int[] randPerm( int n ) {
      int[] perm = new int[n];
      for (int k=0; k<n; ++k) perm[k] = k;
      for (int k=n; k>0; --k) {
         int rand = r.nextInt(k);
         int t = perm[rand];  perm[rand] = perm[k-1];  perm[k-1] = t;
      }
      return( perm );
   }
```

Comment: Can you show us all relevant code?  For instance the `m` and `TWO` variables are not defined in the snippet you gave.

Comment: Ok I updated it to show more methods.

Comment: We need to know what `int[] perm = randPerm( 4 );` does as well. I've made a guess but it'd be nice to know for sure.

Comment: I would assume it just creates a random permutation. Since the maze will be represented by a 2d array (with the value 16 being the walls) then int[] perm looks like a single int array with a random permutation.

Comment: @Chase yes, but knowing what the bounds on the contents of `perm[]` are is crucial to figuring out how the `create()` function works. Could you post the contents of `randPerm()` as well?

Comment: When I print out perm all I get is I@6d06d69c.

Comment: @Chase you would need to use `Arrays.toString(perm)` to get the contents in a readable way. However I'm asking for the code for `randPerm()`, not the actual contents of the array.

Comment: Ok I updated it to show the randPerm method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it took a little while but here's what I've got.

First, the constructor for `Maze` creates a grid of size `nc +2` x `nr +2`, fills all of the border cells with `16` and all of the inner cells with `15`. Then it recursively calls `Create()` starting with the coordinates for a cell in the middle of the grid.

`Create()` starts by calling `int[] perm = randPerm( 4 );`, which creates an array of length `4` containing the ints `0 - 3`, and does a simple random shuffle on it. The contents of `perm[]` are used to select a pair of values from `DX[]` and `DY[]`.

This method uses the `^` operator, which is an `XOR` or `Exclusive Or` function to modify the value of the cell on which the method is called,  and its neighboring cells in random order as dictated by the contents of `perm[]`, `DX[]` and `DY[]` if the content of the cell is `15`. By only checking for `15`, previously modified cells are not altered, and the walls around the border remain unchanged. Additionally, none of the middle cells can be changed to `16` with this method.

Every cell that contains the value `15` is `XOR'd` with a value from `TWO[]`, also selected at random, excluding `16` since `p` is derived from the contents of `perm`, which are constrained between `0 - 3`. By doing this, every cell that contains `15` is changed to a different number - but these numbers can be known ahead of time, since the possible values of the middle cells are constrained by the all possible results of `15 ^ TWO[p]`.

Since the `Random` object `r` is initialized with a `seed` variable, I believe using the same `seed` produces the same maze each time the JVM is initialized. So, by changing the value of `seed` you would produce a different maze which is different from every other value of `seed`. I could be wrong on this point, though, and it might be different every time regardless of the value of `seed`. I'm not familiar with the inner workings of `Random`.

As to how you could know whether the maze is actually solvable or not for every instance, I couldn't say without knowing what each possible value represents in the maze. I'd imagine some numbers are considered impassable, while others aren't?

And given what's been presented, I don't think one could guarantee that *every* maze *has* a valid solution, since this implementation is really just creating a random set of tiles, and there are sure to be some cases where there *isn't* a solution. But, you didn't stipulate that each maze had to be solvable; just unique. If you wanted to guarantee a solvable path every time, there would have to be some additional logic inserted here to make that happen.

Comment: Well the seed is there so that I can produce the exact mazes over and over again with something like this in my main method. maz = new Maze( row, col, 9999 );

Comment: Right, and that makes sense to do that. You could extend that functionality to create "levels" from stored parameters in an external file.

Comment: Ok, so then if I'm creating a 5x5 maze then how many times would the create method be called?

Comment: Once per every cell that contains `15`. So if you create a `new Maze(5, 5, 100)` for a 5x5 maze, it actually creates a 7x7 grid where the borders are set to `16`. Those cells are ignored, so it would be called 25 times recursively starting at the middle. One thing to note about this is that if you try to make a maze that is too large, you might crash the program with a StackOverflowError due to running out of stack space.